# How to include a linux program in my react native app for android

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

I've made a program in nodejs that works fine for linux and windows. Now I'm trying to build the android/ios version.

I tried using the same code in react native but some modules I used in nodejs (typescript ones) are not compatible with react native.

So I thought maybe there is a way that I can build an executable package (using [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg)) and include it in my react native app like creating an interface for my program.

Is there anyway that I can run that nodejs executable inside my react native? Or is there a better way? I'm new to react native and totally confused.

Comment: You might have better luck rewriting the Node script in React Native. Is that an option?

Comment: @Abe some modules im using in nodejs are in type script (e.g. @types/node/events.d.ts). i have no idea how should i use them in react native. can i convert them into commonjs, make react accept .ts or look for alternative modules?

Comment: React Native is totally compatible with Typescript, there are built-in templates for it.